# typescript - Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`0x${string}`

Tags: typescript, nft, wagmi

I am using wagmi for my NFT project using react typescript.

when developing the NFT checking module I got this error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`0x${string}`'

how do I cast my string into `0x${string}`?

below are my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useContractRead, erc721ABI } from "wagmi";

const useNFTChecker = ({
    contractAddress,
    walletAddress,
}: {
    contractAddress: string;///<-- this needs conversion
    walletAddress: string;
}) => {
    const { data, error } = useContractRead({
        address: contractAddress, ///<-- `0x${string}`
        contractInterface: erc721ABI,
        functionName: "balanceOf",
        args: [walletAddress],
    });

    const [hasNFT, setHasNFT] = useState(false);

    ...

    return { hasNFT, error };
};

export default useNFTChecker;
```

Comment: If the library doesn't expose that type you can define your own : `type st = `0x${string}`;` and then `contractAddress: st`

Comment: Shame this library has these typings... They do not provide any benefit in type safety and only cause problems...

Answer (score 6):

You can also solve this by using [viem.sh](https://viem.sh/) `Address` type:

```
import { Address } from 'viem';

const { data, error } = useContractRead({
        address: contractAddress as Address, 
        contractInterface: erc721ABI,
        functionName: "balanceOf",
        args: [walletAddress],
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with needing to typecast string into an address string. I fixed the issue by asserting the string type to `0x${string}` using `as`.

Basically try using the following and see if it fixes the TypeScript error.

```
const { data, error } = useContractRead({
        address: contractAddress as `0x${string}`, 
        contractInterface: erc721ABI,
        functionName: "balanceOf",
        args: [walletAddress],
});
```